# Using LXDE with Kwin window manager

Tags: kde, window-manager, lxde, kwin

Can anybody tell me how I use Kwin as my winow manager with LXDE.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.. Just edit lxde configuration file and replace openbox-lxde with kwin.